# How can I remove one delimiter from elasticsearch tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am using elasticsearch 6.8 for text searching. And I realised that elasticsearch tokenizer breaks text into words by using delimiters listed here: http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Word_Boundaries. I am using `match_phase` to search one of the fields in my document and I'd like to remove one delimiter used by tokenizer.

I did some search and found some solutions like, using `keyword` rather than `text`. This solution will have a big impact on my search function because it doesn't support partial query.

Another solution is to use `keyword` query but use wildcard to support partial query. But this may impact performance on the query. And also, I still like using tokenizer for other delimiters.

A third options is to use `tokenize_on_chars` to define all characters used to tokenize text. But this requires me to list all other delimiters. So I am looking for something like `tokenize_except_chars`.

So is there a easy way for me to take one character out from delimiters tokenizer is using in elasticsearch6.8?

Answer (score 0):

I found elasticsearch supports `protected_words` which can do the job. More info can be found in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html